# What is the standard for documentation style in Bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, documentation

I am currently writing a Bash script that has a number of functions in it and would like to add docs to make other team members understand what the point of the function is.

Is there a standard "style" for documenting Bash scripts and the functions it contains?

Comment: `man` pages for formatting and examples of style: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/how-can-i-add-man-page-entries-for-my-own-power-tools

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128736/66439

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, I try to follow guidelines that are analog to the ones I use with other languages like C.

This includes a function header containing:

- function name, short description and purpose
- list of arguments and return values, with descriptions
- list of all side effects (e.g., changes in variables or files)

Answer (score 24):

I do understand I'm adding an answer to an old question, but I feel the tooling has improved lately and would like to give additional suggestions in order to help out others who are viewing this question.

I have recently found [TomDoc.sh](https://github.com/mlafeldt/tomdoc.sh), which uses TomDoc style comments in shell scripts.  The tool provided can then extract information and generate markdown or plain text documents.

Other tools also exist.  [BashDoc](http://sourcemage.org/bashdoc) is modeled after the JavaDoc syntax, supporting a variety of tags.  With [RoboDoc](http://rfsber.home.xs4all.nl/Robo/robodoc.html) you embed a C-style comment in your Bash code and it extracts the necessary information.  Lastly, Apple uses [HeaderDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html) for its shell scripting.  All three of these have a suggested style for the comments that you write.

If you wish to annotate your code more than generate documentation, [shocco.sh](http://rtomayko.github.io/shocco/) may be what you'd prefer.  It doesn't have a specific format and is designed for you to see human-readable text describing the shell commands that you are running.

Comment: Ah, internet. This is at the bottom of the bashdoc link: "3 Mar 2004 - Finals suck. And there's lots more work too, so this is going to the back burner, if I've still got one of those left. :) Probably for a week or two." 12.5 years later, any updates?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding there is no standard for Bash doc.
But typically you would:

- include a header to your bash file, with your name, copyright,
  contact, and briefly what the script does
- a usage() function that
  explains how to launch and use your function.
- a comment at the top of
  each function to explain what the func does.